# Bash use every word from file after second word

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a file which looks like this:

```
/example/test /example2/test2 Server1,Server2,Server3
/example/test /example2/test2 Server4,Server5,Server6
/example/test /example2/test2 Server7,Server8,Server9
```

I would like to do an SSH on every Server in the line and use the "/example/test" from the same line in which the server stands. I'm trying to do it with arrays, but I'm really new to bash and arrays so I'm having a hard time. Can someone help me or send a link with some examples because I don't know how to google for this?

Comment: If you don't know how to do it, **and** don't know how to search for ideas to start with, I honestly recommend you learn some basics first. Messing with servers via `ssh` is an advanced topic, and you'll need these skills quite often, let alone have an idea what you're actually doing to prevent mistakes.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do with those /example/test* strings. Are they command you want to launch on each server, via ssh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in bash you can use `read`:

```
while read file1 file2 servers; do
    echo "file1 = $file1"
    echo "servers = $servers"
done < file.txt
```

gives you:

```
file1 = /example/test
servers = Server1,Server2,Server3
file1 = /example/test
servers = Server4,Server5,Server6
file1 = /example/test
servers = Server7,Server8,Server9
```